# Clearing map listeners cause draggable option fail in GoogleMaps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have found a strange GM behaviour and don't know is it a bug? I'm disabling and enabling map dragging using this code:

```js
var dragDisabled = false;
function buttonClicked() {
    if (dragDisabled) {
        enableDrag();
        dragDisabled = false;
    } else {
        disableDrag();
        dragDisabled = true;
    }
}

function disableDrag() {
    map.setOptions({
        draggable: false
    });
    // originally add listeners to map here
}

function enableDrag() {
    map.setOptions({
        draggable: true
    });
    google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(map, 'drag');
}

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'),
        {
            zoom: 8,
            center: {
                lat: -37,
                lng: 176
            }
        }
    );
}
```

```css
#map {
    height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#btn-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
  <button id="btn-toggle" onclick="buttonClicked()">Toggle draggable</button>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCKQX3cyZ7pVKmBwE8wiowivW9qH62AVk8&callback=initMap"></script>
```

But in this case I can't disable dragging more than once. But if I delete the map listener clearance everything work fine. Is it a bug? Or is there a way to restore the draggable option working? I didn't found any related info in Google.

**EDIT:** I used maps key from the answer below to make the demonstration code snippet.

**EDIT 2:** The answer to fix this issue is to not to use the `clearInstanceListeners` but `clearListeners` instead. But what if listeners are added dynamically and I don't know which of them should be actually removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use clearListeners instead of clearInstanceListeners

I made a sample app to demonstrate, see code snippet below:

```js
var map;
var draggable = true;
var toggle = document.getElementById("btn-toggle");

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {
      lat: 59.325,
      lng: 18.070
    },
    draggable: draggable
  });
}

toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (draggable) {
    draggable = false;
    disableDrag();
    return;
  }
  draggable = true;
  enableDrag();
});

function disableDrag() {
  map.setOptions({
    draggable: draggable
  });
  // add liteners to map
}

function enableDrag() {
  map.setOptions({
    draggable: draggable
  });
  google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'drag');
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#btn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Draggable</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn-toggle">Toggle Draggable</button>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCKQX3cyZ7pVKmBwE8wiowivW9qH62AVk8&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hide your key pls

Comment: My API key is restricted, thanks for the reminder tho

Comment: Your example is working because you are using the `clearListeners` method. But I'm using the `clearInstanceListeners` method. I tried to change method in your example and your code stopped working.

Comment: So if I don't know what actual listeners were added it will take additional code to account them.

Comment: Do you have any ideas why `clearInstanceListeners` have such side effects?

Comment: If you use clearInstanceListeners, it will disable all events even setZoom, so don't use it on your map instance, unless you want to create another map instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suppose this is a GM bug, because user-scope event listeners should not affect built-in functionality.